# How do I fill out a char array with ascii numbers and then print the characters?

Tags: char, ascii

How do I fill out this array "char[] arr = new char[26];" with ascii numbers so that I can print the letters to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fill the array and print each letter at the same time:

```
public class CharArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] arr = new char[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (char)(i + 97);
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really hard for me to figure it out!

Comment: You can upvote my answer as the best answer then. :p

Comment: Why are people downvoting my question? Do you think it's too simple?

Comment: It is very simple, and normally questions that are considered very simple show lack of research and people down-vote them. You have to show that you tried by submitting your code, explaining what you tried, and you must have a fair bit of knowledge about what you are doing and asking.